# Finding when a webpage updates via Python?

Tags: python

So, I am scraping a webpage and I have a element on the page where it displays an integer, when I scrape that element, i store the plaintext in a variable, then each time it scrapes, i compare the variable to what the plaintext is on the webpage. I am not sure if maybe i need to get a request to the webpage each time?

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
from _overlapped import NULL

from plyer import notification
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

toaster = ToastNotifier()
toaster.show_toast("Notification!", "Alert!", threaded=True, icon_path=NULL, duration=3)

URL = "https://rocketleague.tracker.network/rocket-league/profile/steam/76561198074072333/mmr?playlist=13"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

_title = ""
_message = ""

recent_mmr = "111"


def get_mmr(url):
    results = soup.find_all(class_="stat")
    for stat in results :
        titles = stat.find_all(class_="label")
        for t in titles :
            if(t.text.strip() == "Rating"):
                val = stat.find(class_="value").text.strip()
    return val

def get_rank(url):
    results = soup.find(class_="stat tier")
    rank = results.find(class_="label")
    return rank.text.strip()


_message = "Rank: " + get_rank(URL) + "\n" + "MMR: " + get_mmr(URL)
recent_mmr = get_mmr(URL)

import time
while toaster.notification_active():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    
notification.notify(
    title="Ranked 3v3",
    message= _message,
    app_icon=NULL,
    timeout=10
    )
print(recent_mmr)
recent_mmr = get_mmr(URL)
while True:
    print('running')
    #page = requests.get(URL)
    recent_mmr = get_mmr(URL)
    mmr_temp = recent_mmr
    print(mmr_temp +"(temp mmr)")
    if mmr_temp == recent_mmr:
        print("No update, recent MMR: " + recent_mmr)
        mmr_temp = recent_mmr
        time.sleep(60)
    else:
        notification.notify(
            title="Ranked 3v3",
            message= _message,
            app_icon=NULL,
            timeout=10
        )
        time.sleep(60)
        recent_mmr = get_mmr(URL)
        mmr_temp = recent_mmr
        print("Updated, recent MMR: " + recent_mmr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're scraping the webpage to get the recent_mmr number, copying that to mmr_temp, and then immediately comparing to see if they're equal -- well of course they are, because you *just* copied it!

You need to reorganize the loop a little bit, and copy the mmr variable at the *bottom* of the loop:

```
previous_mmr = None
while True:
    recent_mmr = get_mmr()
    if recent_mmr != previous_mmr:
        print("mmr changed")
    previous_mmr = recent_mmr
```